# Transaction conflict between @Transactional and @EnableJpaRepositories

Tags: spring-data-jpa, transactions

Because of security issues, I have configured two transaction managers. Each transaction manager use a different datasource and a different user:

- datasource1 uses user1. User1 doesn't has access to tables of user2 schema.
- datasource2 uses user2. User2 has also access to tables of user1 schema.

First transaction manager configuration:

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
   basePackages = "com.ieci.mugeju.data.repositories1", 
   entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManager1", 
   transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager1")
   public class Configuration1
{     
  @Bean
  @Primary
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager1()  throws NamingException, IOException
  {            
    EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform");
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource1());
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);  
    em.setJpaDialect(new DefaultJpaDialect());       
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.ieci.mugeju.data.entity" });
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("unificado");                      
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(getJpaPropertyMap());
    em.setMappingResources(mappingResources());

    return em;
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource1()  throws NamingException  {

    return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup("java:/jboss/datasources/datasource1");
  }

  @Primary
  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager1() throws NamingException, IOException {

    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager1().getObject());        
    return transactionManager;
  }


  private HashMap<String, Object> getJpaPropertyMap ()
  {
    ...
  }

  private String[] mappingResources () throws IOException
  {
    ...
  }
```

}

Second transaction manager configuration:

```
@org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
  basePackages = "com.ieci.mugeju.data.repositories2", 
  entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManager2", 
  transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager2")
public class Configuration2
{    
  @Bean
  public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManager2()  throws NamingException, IOException
  {            
    EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
    vendorAdapter.setDatabasePlatform("org.eclipse.persistence.platform.database.OraclePlatform");
    vendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
    
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    em.setDataSource(dataSource2());
    em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);  
    em.setJpaDialect(new DefaultJpaDialect());       
    em.setPackagesToScan(new String[] {"com.ieci.mugeju.data.entity" });
    em.setPersistenceUnitName("denuncias");                      
    em.setJpaPropertyMap(getJpaPropertyMap());
    em.setMappingResources(mappingResources());

    return em;
  }

  @Bean
  public DataSource dataSource2()  throws NamingException  {

    return (DataSource) new JndiTemplate().lookup("java:/jboss/datasources/datasource2");
  }

  @Bean
  public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager2() throws NamingException, IOException {

    JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManager2().getObject());        
    return transactionManager;
  }


  private HashMap<String, Object> getJpaPropertyMap ()
  {
    ...
  }

  private String[] mappingResources () throws IOException
 {
    ...
  }
```

}

I have implemented two repositories:

- Repository1 access database tables of user1 schema.
- Repository2 access database tables of user2 schema

Repository 1:

```
package com.ieci.mugeju.data.repository1;

@Repository
public interface Repository1 extends JpaRepository<Entity1, String>
{
   ... methods ...
}
```

Repository 2:

```
package com.ieci.mugeju.data.repository2;

@Repository
public interface Repository2 extends JpaRepository<Entity2, String>
{
   ... methods ...
}
```

I have implemented a class annotated with @Service. This class have defined several methods which are annotated with @Transactional.

Method1 business logic must be executed with transactionManager1 and method2 business logic must be executed with transactionManager2.

```
@Service
public class MyServicesImpl implements MyServices
{
  @Override
  @Transactional(readOnly = false)
  public String method1(... parameters ...)
  {
     ... do something with repository1 ...
     return rc;
  }

  @Override
  @Transactional(value="transactionManager2", readOnly = false)
  public String method2(... parameters ...)
  {
     ... do something with repository2 ...

     ... do also something with repository1 ...

     return rc;
  }

}
```

Method2 uses with repository 1 and repository 2. I would like all business logic of method2 to be executed with a single database transaction (transactionManager2), but is being executed in two different database transactions.

When method2 is using repository2, transactionManager2 open a transaction, and when is using repository1, transactionManager1 open another transaction. I think that this is happening because the repository1 has been configured through @EnableJpaRepositories annotation in Configuration1. This annotation references transactionManager1.

I don't understand why @EnableJpaRepositories must reference a transaction manager. I think that transaction manager should be only referenced by @Transactional.

What can I do if I want method2 is executed in only one transaction?

Thanks